# .flowconfig file in react-native project is missing

Tags: reactjs, react-native, flowtype

I do not have `.flowconfig` file in my react-native project.
Even then if I add flow locally as :

```
yarn add --dev flow-bin babel-preset-flow
```

and then do flow init, it creates an empty `.flowconfig` file with the latest flow version displayed at end of the file as 0.79.1 . Is it fine? and the rules I had to copy from https://github.com/facebook/react-native/blob/master/.flowconfig which is regularly updated with current flow version(now 0.79.1).

```
React Native Environment Info:
    System:
      OS: macOS High Sierra 10.13.4
      CPU: x64 Intel(R) Core(TM) i7-4770HQ CPU @ 2.20GHz
      Memory: 4.56 GB / 16.00 GB
      Shell: 3.2.57 - /bin/bash
    Binaries:
      Node: 8.11.3 - /usr/local/bin/node
      Yarn: 1.1.0 - /usr/local/bin/yarn
      npm: 5.6.0 - /usr/local/bin/npm
      Watchman: 4.9.0 - /usr/local/bin/watchman
    SDKs:
      iOS SDK:
        Platforms: iOS 12.0, macOS 10.14, tvOS 12.0, watchOS 5.0
    IDEs:
      Android Studio: 3.0 AI-171.4443003
      Xcode: 10.0/10L232m - /usr/bin/xcodebuild
    npmPackages:
      react: 16.4.1 => 16.4.1
      react-native: 0.56.0 => 0.56.0
    npmGlobalPackages:
      create-react-native-app: 1.0.0
      react-native-cli: 2.0.1
      react-native-git-upgrade: 0.2.7
Editor: VSCode
```

Or
should I not use flow at all in the project, cause may be new version of `react-native` takes care of it?